# What should our help centre say about rewrite requests?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Requests to re-write code in a different idiom or using different libraries [are problematic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5045).  Like all Stack Exchange sites, askers are expected to have attempted to solve their own problem before asking, rather than posting "*gimme da codez*".

Do we believe we could help askers by reminding them under the "**To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?**" header that if a particular code style is required, the code should (as far as possible) be in that style?

Note that I'm targeting only the very specific "*How can I rewrite this as <X>?*" requests, as a more general "*Would it help to refactor in a different idiom?*" is generally agreed to be on-topic.

Comment: Do we believe people which post off-topic requests read the help-center at all? If they would, I'd happily spell it out for them. But the longer we make it, the more likely it is people will skip over it.

Comment: I generally point people at our Help Centre when addressing off-topic questions on other sites (usually when somebody has suggested Code Review for a question that needs some work to fit here).  I would hope that at least a few of them follow the link.